# Using Scapy to send data in Header Fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp, udp, scapy

I've used scapy quite a bit to understand how it works. What I am looking for is a pythonic, simple way to add data into the TCP or UDP header fields. I know that for example, the PORT fields can only hold a certain amount of bytes and they need to be in integer form. Is there a clean way I could break up my data into chunks, convert them to an integer and have them just long enough to store in the PORT field? Then obviously have a way to assemble the chunks from the packet back into the original data form?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. what type of "data" are you working with? Could you convert the data into ``ByteArray`` objects, then split them into property sized chucks for the TCP port field?

Comment: the data could be a string or a file (text or image perhaps). What is the advantage of converting it into a byte array?

Comment: Once it's in a ``ByteArray``, it's pretty easy to chunk it up and move the bits to the TCP port field in scapy.

Comment: chunk into groups of 4, ˋstruct.unpackˋ it as an integer, store it in the field, send it. reverse on the other side with ˋstruct.packˋ. but honestly, no clue what your big picture, wanna share it?